# First power supply on 10V output

Tags: power-supply, voltage, transformer, voltage-regulator, analog

I am new to electronics and since I am studying computer engineering (4th semester right now) I am not that familiar with analog electronics.

I have a small project that I want to implement mostly in my free-time which includes a small boombox controlled by STM32 NUCLEO F446RE. Right now I am trying to design the power supply. I am going to post a screenshot along with the files for EAGLE.
Input voltage is 230 V 50 Hz.

[Regulator datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317-n.pdf?ts=1594985324396&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM317-N%253FHQS%253Dti-null-null-sf-df-pf-SEP-wwe%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526dclid%253DCPjthquX1OoCFYbYuwgdALgEGwRegulator)

I want to achieve a 10 V output voltage in order to supply the NUCLEO F446RE and the TAS6424L-Q1 amplifier.
I will give you both eagle and circuit lab schematic.

[image: Eagle Schematic]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzRO7S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What do you need to learn that you can't do on your own?  Specs? compute  heat rise? choose parts and layout?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What's your 10 V output current requirement? 100 ohm for R4 is too low for any normal 20 mA LED. R3 value is very non-standard. Try to stick to E12 series.

Comment: I forgot to change the value of R4, it is the default, I think the calculated is around 3.8K. Nucleo draws around 250 mA on 10V using the datasheet information. Amplifier I want to supply typically draws 15 mA from the supply (Ivdd = 15mA) . Datasheets :
Amplifier : https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tas6424l-q1.pdf?ts=1595247865222&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTAS6424L-Q1
Nucleo : https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f446re.html

Comment: What is your question? Do you have a specific problem you're looking to address?

Comment: Is that functional, will it work or is there something bad in the design.I am pretty new on simulating that complex circuits without using multisim, I used multisim and it worked as expected.

Comment: Neither of your load devices requires the very small performance increase added by D1 and its components.  You can stick to the circuit on page 1 of the datasheet.  Note - you should add the output capacitors recommended.

Comment: You will need to pay attention to heat also.  This is dropping 5V - by your diagram - so it will absorb 7.5W @  the regulator's max 1.5A current.  That datasheet shows a temperature rise ranging from 23 C°/W (170 C° at 7.5W) to over 180 C°/W (1350 C° at 7.5W !!) - depending on package - so you could easily fry the regulator if you are not very careful.

Comment: @mbedded Do you think that a fan can help with that?

Comment: A heat sink would be the first step; the junction-to-case spec is about 1 C°/W, so the total temperature rise may be 20-30 C° with a good heatsink on the TO-220 package.  That should be enough, and anyway you want more surface area for a fan.

Comment: @mbedded There's going to be a boombox and probably I will use heatsinks and some fans for cooling, I think that amplifier needs a heatsink as well(I have not reviewed the amp yet)

Comment: It's not adviseable to make a DC-DC conversion when powering an audio amplifier. An audio amplifier is power hungry (a lot of amperes), and it's better power them directly with the transformer's rectified output. Even if you would convert this voltage to a lower one for powering your MCU, it would be better to use a buck converter, instead of a LM317 circuit that will dissipate all the voltage difference as heat.

Comment: For the MCU supply, you could have a separate transformer that steps down to 5 V RMS, with a rectifier and 7805 and/or 78033 regulator.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of "boombox" is this, that its amplifier draws only 15 mA?

I fear that you are looking at the wrong parameters of this chip. This is a linear amplifier with digital inputs.

Ivdd = 15mA is the requirement for just the logic (digital) part of this chip, whose voltage is "V Logic". The amplifier part of this chip needs a lot of amperes for the audio amplifier part (PVdd in datasheet).

Look at item 7.1 of TAS6424L-Q1 amplifier's datasheet:

[image]

[image]

Definitely, this amplifier needs much more than only 15 mA.

This is a linear amplifier with digital inputs. Its audio amplifier part can support a 4.5V to 18 V power supply. There's no need to reduce the 15V input for power the amplifier, and it's not advisable for a power-hungry device like this.

It would be better if the amplifier could run directly with the rectified 15V output from transformer, and the LM317 circuit will be used only for the digital part feeding 10v to the microcontroller (I didnt't read the MCU's datasheet; does it really needs those 10V? You may need for some kind of level shifting to connect this MCU with the digital inputs of TAS6424L)

If your objective is learning, go on with your project. But if you just want to build the boombox, think about buying a switched 12V power supply.

Comment: I wanted to use that supply in order to "feed" the MCU and the amplifier. Maybe I will use the 15 V of the rectified output as supply to the amp and then use the LM 317 to feed the MCU .

Comment: Forgive me, but: I hope that you are aware that the amplifier chip itself has **two** supply requirements, one for the logic part (about 3.5V) and another one for the power audio output. And, besides the logical part of the amplifier chip, you must feed the NUCLEO board, too. NUCLEO can be feed with 3.3V directly, 5V, and 7-12V. The 3.3V and 5V options demand a more complicated power source. If you opt for NUCLEO's 7-12V input, it is better stick to the lower range of this voltage (reducing the voltage that has to be lowered by NUCLEO's internal regulator).

Comment: I would suggest using two regulators like [these](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32742116421.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.51e67346NVOp5n&s=p&ad_pvid=202007201441492127270806691750002051344_3&algo_pvid=7f70d0d2-d454-4d45-a051-373a851d3ee8&algo_expid=7f70d0d2-d454-4d45-a051-373a851d3ee8-2&btsid=0ab6f8ad15952813096354918e6b92&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_): a 9V one (or the adjustable one set at 7.5V) for NUCLEO, and a 3.3V one for the amplifier.

Comment: So I connect pvdd to transformer rectified output. Vdd and NUCLEO supply to step down modules one of 3.3V and 9V respectfully.

Comment: Yes. The amplifier's logic part can cope with 3.3V supply accordingly. But NUCLEO is different: although it uses 3.3V, it has complex power requirements, its [datasheet](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f446re.html#resource) says: _In case VIN, E5V or +3.3V is used to power (...) source must comply with the standard EN-60950-1: 2006+A11/2009, and must be Safety Extra Low Voltage (SELV) with limited power capability._ So, instead of build this kind of supply to NUCLEO, you just feed it with 9V from the off-the-shelf regulator, and NUCLEO's own voltage regulator will do the job.

Comment: I guess I connect pvdd across the filter and not before right? Apart from that, I will feed 9V to nucleo through the pins as the datasheet says using the step down

Comment: I will review the whole schematic and then post it as a comment below. Please review it and tell me your opinion. Thanks!

Comment: I reviewed the power supply [link](https://imgur.com/a/HLzEZo8)

Comment: Please add me information into your question so that all relevant information is in one place. The schematic should be posted as an image rather than a link.